# Displaying table with an overflow using two tables

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, overflow

I looked online for a solution. I don't want to use jQuery I want to use pure css. One of the solutions was to use two tables. Because the `tr` doesn't stretch the whole way across the screen the `th` and the `td` don't line up.

```
#regionItemListing {
 height: 100% !important;
 min-height: 557px;
 max-height: 557px;
 /*overflow: auto;*/
 /*panel style*/
 padding-bottom: 12px;
 background-color: #ffffff;
 border: 1px solid #dddddd;
 border-radius: 4px;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
 box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
 /*Fix margin left*/
 margin-left: 5px;
 margin-right: 0px;
 width: 78%;}

#regionItemListing thead, tbody {
    display: block;
}



#regionItemListing tbody {
    height: 17% !important;
    min-height: 507px;
    max-height: 507px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: If your `th` and `td` don't line up, shouldn't you just use `colspan`?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is hard to understand, but by using two tables your table headings and table data will not match up unless you give them a standard width:

Place the two tables inside of a div with the id "myID"
and then add css that looks like this:

```
#myID {
  width: 500px;
}
table {
  width: 100%;
}
th {
   width: 10%;
}
td {
   width: 10%;
}
```

And see if that helps.